# Count mysql union type query

Tags: php, mysql

I have a union type query. How can I count the number of rows it queries?

```
mysql_query(
    "  (SELECT 1 as sort_col,performerid,pic0 
          FROM $table 
          WHERE performerid IS NOT NULL $performeridSql) 
    UNION 
       (SELECT 2 as sort_col,performerid,pic0 
          FROM $table 
          WHERE performerid IS NOT NULL 
              $categorySql $buildSql 
              $breastsize $haircolor $age $ethnicity 
              $willingnessSql) 
          ORDER BY sort_col");
```

Comment: What's the meaning of all those variables after IS NOT NULL?

Comment: One example of how to do it: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php#81348 or are you looking for more of an explain plan?

Comment: Note the mysql extension is outdated and on its way to deprecation. PDO or mysqli should be used instead, both of which offer many advantages, such as prepared statements.

Comment: Ty very much, I am really a newb:) , if you can give me a better coding, would be greatly appreciated. The variables are other sql conditions

Comment: Breast size? Willingness? Just what is this for??!?

Comment: If you need a PDO tutorial, try ["Writing MySQL Scripts with PHP and PDO"](http://www.kitebird.com/articles/php-pdo.html). You're going to need to study up on data access layers, [prepared statements](http://blog.oudamou.co.cc/2011/07/parallels-between-prepared-statements.html), relational database design and the like.

Comment: For now I just need a way to count this type of query

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply count the subquery results...

```
SELECT COUNT(t.*) FROM
(   (SELECT 1 AS sort_col,performerid,pic0 
       FROM $table 
       WHERE performerid IS NOT NULL 
         $performeridSql) 
  UNION 
    (SELECT 2 AS sort_col,performerid,pic0 
       FROM $table 
       WHERE performerid IS NOT NULL 
         $categorySql $buildSql 
         $breastsize $haircolor $age $ethnicity 
         $willingnessSql)
  ORDER BY sort_col)
) AS t
```

Comment: Yes, as you can see, I've used "AS t" in order to tell MySQL to use an alias of your subquery.

Answer (score 0):

If you need the results in addition to the count, the likes of [`mysqli_result::num_rows`](http://php.net/mysqli_result.num_rows) or [`PDOStatement::rowCount`](http://php.net/PDOStatement.rowCount) will return what you want. Otherwise, run your query as a subquery, then apply the `COUNT` aggregate function to the result.