# Mysql error in a count query which counts a union subquery

Tags: php, mysql

Can you please check this mysql query and maybe help with what's wrong with it?

When I run it through mysql as my host i get this error:

*#1248 - Every derived table must have its own alias*

Here is the code:

```
mysql_query("
SELECT COUNT(*) 
FROM 
(

(SELECT 1 as sort_col,id,pic0 FROM `cronjob_reloaded` WHERE id IS NOT NULL AND id LIKE '%car%') 

UNION 

(SELECT 2 as sort_col,id,pic0 FROM `cronjob_reloaded` WHERE id IS NOT NULL AND category IN ('bmw')) 

ORDER BY sort_col

)
")
```

Ty!

PS. I have posted an unclear question some time ago, can a admin please delete that one? And sorry for any inconvenience. The question is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8580039/count-mysql-union-type-query)

Comment: as the error says add aliases so poor mysql wont get confused as to which table you are making reference to.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Count mysql union type query](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8580039/count-mysql-union-type-query)

Comment: Yes, I have asked maybe an admin can delete that one, was unclear

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the error says, derived tables must be aliased.

```
SELECT COUNT(*) 
FROM 
(

(SELECT 1 as sort_col,id,pic0 FROM `cronjob_reloaded` WHERE id IS NOT NULL AND id LIKE '%car%') 

UNION 

(SELECT 2 as sort_col,id,pic0 FROM `cronjob_reloaded` WHERE id IS NOT NULL AND category IN ('bmw')) 

ORDER BY sort_col

) q /* I added the alias "q" */
```

Comment: Your 2nd version is not entirely equivalent to the OP's. Notice the `SELECT 1` and `2`. He is doing a `UNION ALL` really.